# Possible to use CLLocation with English Localization no matter what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, location, geocoding

So, I'm using CLLocation to get a users City and Country in my app. However, it has a behavior I don't like:

If I'm in the US, and I set the Sim location to Lulea, Sweden, the strings it gets are exactly that. However, I have a user there, and the CLLocation spits out a localized version: Luleå, Sverige. This doesn't really work for most of the world, and I'd like to get all the names in English if possible. Does anyone know how?

Thanks!